# UI framework to design html forms

Tags: jquery, json, html, dom

We are planning to design some complex forms with HTML. 
Is there any robust and flexible UI framework availble to do this?
What would be the best approach to start this?

We are looking framework where once the form has been submitted, the form data should be available as xml in business layer.

Please help.

Comment: Are you looking to program UIs with a programming framework or build UIs with a form development product from a vendor?

Comment: We are looking to program UIs with a programming framework

Answer (score 0):

Almost all browser frameworks provide the capability to assist with form creation, validating entered data and returning that data to a server for processing.  The common suspects (in alphabetical order) are:

- Angular
- Dojo
- Ember
- Knockout
- jQuery
- Polymer

All of these aim to provide JavaScript frameworks that aid and assist the programmer to achieve function easier than hand coding the HTML code themselves.  Data can be submitted from forms in web pages using these frameworks to a Servlet or other receiver.  Typically, the data is passed a HTML FORM encoded data or as JSON payloads via Ajax but some of the frameworks can convert to XML before transmission.  On the server, the data can be processed and converted into XML representation as needed.